# Have some ETH stuck in a contract

Tags: solidity, remix

I have some ETH stuck in a contract. Can someone please help me reverse it back to my Metamask wallet?

Contract Address -
0x68Ea394C82BC0A653506084fe2643EEa2917554d

Metmask Wallet Address -
0x19f286804dB22E07d705821613fe8667716D159a

Any help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded.

Best,
Kishan

Comment: Please verify the source code of the contract in Etherscan - it's next to impossible to help without the source code

Comment: ...although the contract doesn't hold any Ethers. So they are not stuck there - they have already been forwarded to another address

Comment: Do you need the code that I used on Remix? Actually, I came across some video on YouTube about Frontloading transactions on Uniswap and now my ETH seems to be stuck there but yes in reality its been forwarded to the mempool router address and its stuck there. I'm unable to get it back to my contract nor my wallet.

Comment: Yes it's a known scam, what you call the "mempool router address" is just the scammers address. Unfortunately your ether is lost, and theres no way for you to get it back :/ I suggest you report the video to youtube and contact your country's police

Comment: Ohh I see. Thanks for letting me know.